# error while loading shared libraries - wrong ELF class

Tags: ros, tabletop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I was running the tabletop_object_detector and despite always previously working, a new error has arisen (potentially as a result of "rosmake"ing some files?):

/code/shared/sr-ros-interface/public_safety/shadow_robot/tabletop_object_detector/bin/tabletop_complete_node: error while loading shared libraries: libpcl_ros_io.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64
[tabletop_complete_node-3] process has died [pid 22274, exit code 127].
log files: /home/ros/.ros/log/07310876-b471-11e0-912d-00252274d18f/tabletop_complete_node-3*.log

A google search leads me to believe it's an issue with the fact that it is a 64-bit library when it should be a 32-bit one - any ideas how to fix that? the error is only with "libpcl_ros_io"

Thanks for the help in advance as ever!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10694/error-while-loading-shared-libraries---wrong-elf-class/) by [rohan_k](https://answers.ros.org/users/856/rohan_k/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2011-07-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2011-07-22**:
Do you have a 32 or 64bit system and what is your other ROS code build on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

no activity in > 1 month, closing

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0